# new Date() - object is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm working in AngularJS, but I'm experiencing an error when working with dates. I currently have one Unix timestamp, and I need to find out if it is today.

```
        var start = new Date();
            start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var end = new Date();
            end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

        // Convert to Second/Unix Timestamp
        start = Math.round(start.getTime() /1000);
        end = Math.round(end.getTime() /1000);

        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var date = Date.utcDateToTimestamp(list[i].date_utc);
            if(start < date && end > date)
               console.log('this one is today');
        }
```

However, I'm getting an error in the console:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

I've looked into it, and it seems I can't even create a new Date object without this being thrown:

```
var start = new Date();
```

Is this something really obvious, or..?

Comment: Pretty sure `setHours` takes *one* argument, namely the hours...

Comment: `setHours(hour,min,sec,millisec)` - this isnt' the issue though, it wont even allow me to create the date object.

Comment: how Date.utcDateToTimestamp is defined? This is the only "might be an object while used as function" element in your code.

Comment: @Alias ... huh. How did I never know about this? >_>

Comment: Oh god... I had a service called Date... stupid me xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe look for simple solution:

```
//Get today's date
var todaysDate = new Date();

//call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if(inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
{
    //Date equals today's date
}
```

You don't need to check for hours, reset hours to zero and compare them. You are interested in year, month, day only:)

Comment: Although not the issue, I'll accept this as it also helped me, nice solution!